# Structure of finitely generated Abelian group

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem, finitely-generated

Let $N=<x,y>$ and $|x|=|y|=p$ for some prime $p$. Assume aswell that $xy=yx$ so N is Abelian, then *the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups* tells us that either $N \simeq   \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $N \simeq   \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times    \mathbb{Z}_{p} $. Both options have order $p^2=|N|$ but since $gcd(p,p)\neq 1$ the Chinese remainder theorem tells us that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \not\simeq  \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times    \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ .

I am supposed to find that the second option, $N \simeq   \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times    \mathbb{Z}_{p} $, is the case, but not sure what singles that one out?

Comment: What singles that one out? Well, all the nontrivial the elements have order $p$. So it cannot be the other group.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have now corrected it.

Comment: I can't understand what the question here is: " to find....a group"? Do you mean how to construct a group isomophic to $\;\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Assuming you meant the final paragraph, you didn't read the whole sentence: "I am supposed to find that the second option [...] is the case" seems mostly fine to me.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I read that...and again: what does "find" mean here? The OP hasn't said...

Comment: @DonAntonio You mean to say that you read "I am supposed to find that the second option is the case", and you seriously cannot infer what meaning that sentence tries to convey? Sure, it may not be perfect Queen's English, but it seems obvious to me. Here is an alternative phrasing of the focal paragraph to help you out: "The answer that I am supposed to get is the second option, $N\simeq \Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p$, but I am not sure how to tell that that's the correct solution."

Comment: *final paragraph, not focal. Damn mobile.

Comment: @Arthur I meant to say that I'd rather have the OP saying what he meant than you talking for him, so please stop. Thanks

Comment: Excuse my Denglish, and thanks for translating correctly into Queen's English Arthur :) And Dietrich, I am not sure I understand your comment since for some x^i*y^j \in N, we have (x^i*y^j)^p=x^ip*y^jp=x^i*y^j /neq e